# Change the TD value inside a particular Div Tag inside using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I have the following HTML Table,

```
<table id="items">
   <tr class="total_up">

          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>

        <td class="total-value" id="total"><div id="totalone">$875.00</div></td> 
      </tr>

       <tr class="disc" id="disc">

          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Discount</td>
          <td class="total-value" id="discount"><div id="discountid"><input type="text" name="disco" class="dis"/></div> </td>
      </tr>



      <tr class="tax_up">
          <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">tax</td>
          <td class="total-value" id="tax"><div id="tax">00</div></td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

When i click on the button with id Discount, I need to change the value to the TD inside the div Tag with id "total" and set its value to another JavaScript variable?I tried the following, but it's not working.

```
 $(".discountbtn").click(function(){

var test=$("#items #disc .dis").val(); //Easiest method


    console.log("lol");
    console.log(test);
    var tot = roundNumber(test,2);

    var new_tot=window.finale-tot;
    console.log(window.finale);

    console.log(new_tot);

    $('#items #totalone').html("$"+new_tot);

   //alert("button");


});
```

Comment: Two elements have the same id.

Comment: Updated the code. Sorry

Comment: can you post everything?? like ``var test=$("#items #disc .dis").val();`` ??

Comment: code updated again :) @PlatinumIndustries

Comment: Here "discount" id given to the two different element, fix it

Comment: @GuRu: What about now?

Comment: try my answer, i already changed it

Comment: ur function roundNumber???

Comment: i think setting working but the calculation is wrong

Comment: @ShriyaR: Calculation was correct. It was a minor glitch in the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with my code that help you

change HTML `<div id="totalone">$875.00</div>` to `$<span id="totalone">875.00</span>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#discountbtn").click(function(){
        var test=$("#items #disc .dis").val(); 
        console.log(test);

        var oldTotal = $("#totalone").text();
        console.log(oldTotal);

        var tot = Math.round(test * 100) / 100;
        var new_tot=parseFloat(oldTotal)-tot;
        console.log(new_tot);

        $('#items #total').html(new_tot); //It was a jQuery selector glitch.
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It's not working. I put console.log all the way upto the final answer and the math is right. However, the line   $('#items #totalone').html("$"+tot); is not working.

Comment: @Ashif Shereef that's work for me please, check it out https://jsfiddle.net/wq9jnfwa/

Comment: No luck :(. What is happening.

Comment: you what actual need like that
new total = old total - subtract value

Comment: Yes. its a subtraction operation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101655/discussion-between-guru-and-ashif-shereef).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#items #totalone').html("$"+new_tot);
```

Comment: total_up is the TR class.